# Testing Proxies with Hardhat

Tags: solidity, testing, hardhat, upgrading

I have a smart contract that was inherited from UUPSUpgradeable smart contract. I am deploying it first as v1 and then deploying my proxy contract. Here is my proxy contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.11;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Proxy is UUPSUpgradeable, Ownable {

    constructor(address _impl) {
        _upgradeTo(_impl);
    }
    
    function _authorizeUpgrade(address) internal override onlyOwner {}
}
```

I am giving the v1.address as constructor parameter to the proxy. Am I doing the right thing? If I am, how can I send tx to proxy to delegate? I am using hardhat for testing, as you can see in the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `attach` to test an already deployed contract with some specific contract ABI. Assuming your `v1` contract is named `V1`, you may test the proxy contract with `hardhat-waffle` like this:

```
const V1 = await ethers.getContractFactory("V1");
const v1 = await V1.deploy();

const Proxy = await ethers.getContractFactory("Proxy");
const proxy = await Proxy.deploy(v1.address);

const proxiedV1 = await V1.attach(proxy.address);
```

you can then use the `proxiedV1` object to call `V1`'s methods with the `proxy` contract. For example if V1 is an ERC20Upgradeable contract with an `initialize` method (as per the UUPS patten):

```
await proxiedV1.initialize();
await proxiedV1.transfer(addr1, value1);
console.log(await proxiedV1.balanceOf(addr1));
```